# Font CORS issue is from another domain

Tags: reactjs, heroku, fonts, create-react-app

My React App is on **Heroku** and I have added 2 domains to the App.

For example,

```
prod.tosky.com
prod.tosky-app.com
```

But when I access to `prod.tosky.com`, I am getting the CORS issue.

The error is

```
Access to font at 'https://prod.tosky-app.com/static/media/TitilliumWeb-Bold.08d37409.ttf' from origin 'https://prod.tosky.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

This also happens when I access to access to `prod.tosky-app.com`

Not sure why front is from another domain.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Are you using webpack?

Comment: Yes, @NikolaCojcic

Comment: Can you check what the publicPath is in webpack config?

Comment: It is set as PUBLIC_URL env.

Comment: I see. What is the value of PUBLIC_URL?

Comment: It is prod.tosky-app.com

Answer (score 0):

I have updated `publicURL` in **Webpack** config

Before:

```
const publicURL = process.env.PUBLIC_URL
```

Now:

```
const publicURL = '/'
```